# How to use this impl<T> From<T> for B where T: AsRef<A> twice: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<_>` for type `B`

Tags: rust

My code is:

```
struct A {}

struct B {}

struct C {}

impl<T> From<T> for B
where
    T: AsRef<A>,
{
    fn from(_: T) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl<T> From<T> for B
where
    T: AsRef<C>,
{
    fn from(_: T) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

The error it gives me is

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<_>` for type `B`
  --> src/main.rs:59:1
   |
50 | impl<T> From<T> for B
   | --------------------- first implementation here
...
59 | impl<T> From<T> for B
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `B`
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible because you might have a type `D` which implements both `AsRef<A>` and `AsRef<C>`. And then which implementation of `From<D> for B` should the compiler pick?